# Pair initialization in declaration, How to do it?

Tags: c#

```
Frame<int, int>[] test = new Frame<int, int>[3] {{2,5},{3,6},{4,7}};
```

Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field initializer. Try using a new expression instead.

How is that possible?

Comment: what's the structure of frame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that the literal `{2,3}` by itself does not represent a `Frame<int, int>`. It is only used as part of an *initializer*, which means it has to accompany an instantiation, like this:

```
Frame<int, int>[] test = new Frame<int, int>[]
{
    new Frame<int, int>(2, 5),
    new Frame<int, int>(3, 6),
    new Frame<int, int>(4, 7)
};
```

There is a way around this. If you define a type with the following two characteristics, you can get the syntax you want:

1. The type must implement `IEnumerable`. (Actually, it doesn't even need to *really* implement it; it just needs to be defined as implementing it. In other words the `GetEnumerator` method doesn't have to do anything.)
2. The type must have an `Add` method.

Now, the `Add` requirement defines how the initialization syntax works. So here's an example, using a `FrameCollection` class designed purely for initialization of a `Frame<int, int>[]` array:

```
// Skeleton code for illustration only.
class Frame<T1, T2>
{
    public Frame(T1 x, T2 y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public T1 X { get; private set; }
    public T2 Y { get; private set; }
}

// IEnumerable (non-)implementation for initializer syntax.
class FrameCollection : IEnumerable
{
    List<Frame<int, int>> _frames;

    public FrameCollection()
    {
        _frames = new List<Frame<int, int>>();
    }

    // Add method to enable initialization syntax using { x, y }.
    public void Add(int x, int y)
    {
        _frames.Add(new Frame<int, int>(x, y));
    }

    public Frame<int, int>[] ToArray()
    {
        return _frames.ToArray();
    }

    // This method doesn't technically need to do anything.
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

Because the `FrameCollection` class defines an `Add` method which accepts two `int` parameters, we can now write code like this:

```
var frames = new FrameCollection
{
    { 2, 5 },
    { 3, 6 },
    { 4, 7 }
};

foreach (Frame<int, int> frame in frames.ToArray())
{
    Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1})", frame.X, frame.Y);
}
```

Output:

```
(2, 5)
(3, 6)
(4, 7)
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it shouldn't something like this?

```
Frame<int, int>[] test = new Frame<int, int>[3] {
    new Frame<int, int>(2,5),
    new Frame<int, int>(3,6),
    new Frame<int, int>(4,7)
};
```